# How to send a command properly into docker container?

Tags: bash, docker, shell, syntax, double-quotes

I can execute the command below in my terminal succesfully.
**command:**

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=egm96-15.gtx" -t_srs "+datum=WGS84 +no_def" input.tif output.tif
```

Now, I want to store this command into a variable and expand this command inside a docker container.

My script `run.sh` looks like the following. I first store my target command into `mycommand` and run the container with the command as input.

```
mycommand=$@;
docker run -ti --rm osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest /bin/bash -c "cd $(pwd); ${mycommand}"
```

And then I execute the `run.sh` as following.

```
bash run.sh gdalwarp -s_srs "+datum=WGS84 +no_defs +geoidgrids=egm96-15.gtx" -t_srs "+datum=WGS84 +no_def" input.tif output.tif
```

**Issue:**

1. I was hoping everything after `bash run.sh` can be store literally into the `mycommand` variable.
2. And inside the docker container, the `mycommand` can be expand and execute literally. But it looks like that the double quote in my original command will be lost during this process.

Thank you.

Comment: `"cd $(pwd);` that is odd, why would you want to cd to the same directory as beeing on host?

Comment: @KamilCuk The directory structure inside the container is the same as my host. So, I want the working directory inside the container to be the same as my host is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the command as argument and then invoke `"$@"` inside the shell. I prefer mostly single quotes.

```
docker run -ti --rm osgeo/gdal:ubuntu-small-latest \
    /bin/bash -c 'cd '"$(pwd)"' && "$@"' -- "$@"
```

If only you want `cd` just let docker change the directory with `-w`. In Bash `$PWD` will be faster then `pwd` command.

```
docker run ... -w "$PWD" image "$@"
```

Note that `"$(pwd)"` is not properly quoted inside child shell - the result will undergo word splitting and filename expansion. Anyway, I recommend `declare -p` and Bash arrays (and `declare -f` for functions) to transfer data between Bash-es. `declare` will always properly quote all stuff, so that child shell can properly import it.

```
cmd=("$@")
pwd=$PWD
work() {
   cd "$pwd"
   "${cmd[@]}"
}
docker ... bash -c "$(declare -p pwd cmd); $(declare -f work); work"
```

Research: when to use quoting in shell, difference between single and double quotes, *word splitting* expansion and how to prevent it, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes , bash arrays, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 .

Comment: It works like a charm. But I don't understand several things here. First, why doesn't it work if `'"$(pwd)"'` becomes `"$(pwd)"`. I think everything inside single quote is treated literally and my path doesn't have any special character (/home/john/Downloads). Second, would the single quotes around `cd '"$(pwd)"' && "$@"` make it treated literally and the expansion `"$@"` not working? Third, why does it run `"$@"` twice? Fourth, I think the double-dash `--` represents the end of options list of `/bin/bash`. So, the last `"$@"` is the one that executes my command, right? Thank you.

Comment: `why doesn't it work if '"$(pwd)"' becomes "$(pwd)"` research difference between single and double quotes. Also, it's not great anyway, because the result of `$(pwd)` undergoes word splitting - it won't work with paths with spaces. `would the single quotes around cd '"$(pwd)"' && "$@" make it treated literally` `$(pwd)` is inside double quotes, the rest is literally, yes. `the expansion "$@" not working?` `bash -c` expands `"$@"`. `why does it run "$@" twice?` First script passes arguments to `bash -c` as arguments, then `bash -c` uses arguments to run a program.

Comment: `So, the last "$@" is the one that executes my command, right?` The `-- "$@"` passes arguments _as arguments_ to child shell `bash -c`, then `'... "$@"'` inside `bash -c` child shell executes the command. There are two shells - your script and child `bash -c` run inside the container. `--` is not actually end of options, it's `$0` inside child bash, ex. `bash -c 'echo $0 $1' this_is_0 this_is_1`, see `man bash`. Some people use `_`, it's just a placeholder.